Limit of sequence defined by an integral
Given a sequence $I_n = \int_{2\pi n}^{2\pi(n+1)}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$, prove the sequence is monotone and find the limit $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}I_n$.
How should I tackle these problems?
It is not an easily integrable function, so I can't rely on finding the primitive. I also tried the mean-value theorem, but the function inside is not monotone on the interval $[2\pi n, 2\pi (n+1)]$. I also thought that I could do $ \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}(I_1 + I_2 + I_3 + ... + I_n) = \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{2\pi}^{2\pi(n+1)}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \pi/2 ?$ which is convergent, and since each term is positive, it would make the sequence convergent as well.
If you can give me some hints or point me out to resources, I would much appreciate it.

$\lim {n\rightarrow \infty} \int{2\pi}^{2\pi(n+1)}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx \ne \pi/2$. The correct limit is $\lim {n\rightarrow \infty} \int{\color{red}0}^{2\pi(n+1)}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \pi/2$

thank you, I also thought it looked a bit shady

Your idea could be useful: If a series converges, then its general term tends to $0$. If you can use the fact that  $\int_0 ^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \pi/2$, then $\sum_{n=\color{red}0}^\infty I_n = \pi/2$ is convergent, which means $I_n$ tends to $0$. However proving that the integral $\int_0 ^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ is convergent is usually proved through  the properties of the sequence $I_n$.

that makes sense now

You can exploit the periodicity of the sine function.
Via the change of variables $y=x-2\pi n$, we get $$I_n=\int_{2\pi n}^{2\pi(n+1)}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin (y+2\pi n)}{y+2\pi n}dy=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin (y)}{y+2\pi n}dy$$
As $y\geq 0$ we get $$|I_n|\leq \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{|\sin (y)|}{|y+2\pi n|}dy\leq \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2\pi n}dy=\dfrac{1}{n},  $$
so $I_n\to 0$.
To prove the monotonic behavior, just notice that $$I_n=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin (y)}{y+2\pi n}dy+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin (y)}{y+2\pi n}dy=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin (y)}{y+2\pi n}dy+\int_{0}^{\pi}-\frac{\sin (y)}{y+2\pi n+\pi}dy=\\\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(y)\left(\dfrac{1}{y+2\pi n}-\dfrac{1}{y+2\pi n +\pi}\right)dy=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(y)\dfrac{\pi}{(y+2\pi n)(y+2\pi n +\pi)}dy,$$
which clearly decreases.

thank you very much, that is so clear!
